# PIL.ImageGrab , grab() and load() functions in thread

Tags: python, multithreading, function, python-imaging-library

I want to create a game bot but with threading.

When script founds game screen works 1 time and stop with this message "Process finished with exit code 0". But scrpit can not found the game screen, works truly...

How can I fix this problem? Thanks a lot.

```
class POT(Thread):
    global x, y


    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.running = True

    def run(self):
        while self.running:
            try:
                x, y = locateCenterOnScreen('menu.PNG')
                text = grab().load()[x - 670, y - 730]
                text2 = grab().load()[x - 757, y - 730]
                if (text[0] < 150):
                    for z in range(3):
                        press('0')
                        sleep(0.05)
                        release('0')
                        sleep(0.05)
                    print('HP USED')

                    if text2[0] < 150:
                        for z in range(3):
                            press('6')
                            sleep(0.025)
                            release('6')
                            sleep(0.025)
                            press('5')
                            sleep(0.033)
                            release('5')
                            sleep(0.033)
                        print('INTUITION USED 6')
                        print('AURA USED 5')
                print(x, y)
                return x, y
            except:
                print("GAME SCREEN NOT FOUND...")



bot=POT()
bot.start()
bot.join()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing `return x, y`.

That will break the `while self.running` loop, so the thread ends, and with it, your program.

As an aside:

- you don't need a thread for this since your program is doing nothing else than this loop.
- you should never, ever use a bare `try: except:` block. It will also catch `SystemExit`s and `KeyboardInterrupt`s.

  - If you'd use `try: except Exception:` instead of `try: except:`, you'd want to use `traceback.print_exc()` so you know the *actual* exception.